# Python Ctypes Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, ctypes

With the help of folks here I was able to get most of my ctype integration working in my python script.

[Python3 processing ctypes data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976145/python3-processing-ctypes-data)

I am interfacing with the Fanuc Focas library to pull in data from CNC machines. All of the c functions that don't need me to send arguments work, but I am not able to get any of them with additional arguments to work.

So my question is, how to do I debug this? (or how do I fix it if you see the issue). I have tried using gdb, but can't seem to figure that out.

For example, I can run this with no issue:

```
focas.cnc_statinfo2(libh, statinfo)
```

I cannot get this one to work: (where I have to supply the spindle number)

```
spindleNumber = ctypes.c_short(1)
ret = focas.cnc_rdspload(libh, spindleNumber, sploadA)
```

I believe my problem lies with the "spindleNumber" variable. It is expecting a ctype short, I have tried:

```
focas.cnc_rdspload(libh, 1, sploadA)

focas.cnc_rdspload(libh, '1', sploadA)

focas.cnc_rdspload(libh, c_short(1), sploadA)

focas.cnc_rdspload(libh, ctypes.c_short(1), sploadA)
```

Every one just results in the vague "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error" and it does not generate a core file anywhere that I can find. So I am struggling to do any troubleshooting.

If it helps, here is the prototype: (https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/position/cnc_rdspload)

```
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_rdspload(unsigned short FlibHndl, short sp_no, ODBSPN *serialspindle);


typedef struct odbspn {
    short   datano;                 /* Spindle number. */
    short   type;                   /* Not used. */
    short   data[MAX_SPINDLE];      /* Spindle data. */
} ODBSPN ;      /* MAX_SPINDLE is maximum number of spindle. */
```

Full Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path
import os

#load fanuc focus cpp library
libpath = ("libfwlib32.so")
focas = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
focas.cnc_startupprocess.restype = ctypes.c_short
focas.cnc_exitprocess.restype = ctypes.c_short
focas.cnc_allclibhndl3.restype = ctypes.c_short
focas.cnc_freelibhndl.restype = ctypes.c_short

focas.cnc_sysinfo_ex.restype = ctypes.c_short
focas.cnc_rdspload.argtype = ctypes.c_short
focas.cnc_rdspload.restype = ctypes.c_short

ret = focas.cnc_startupprocess(0, "focas.log")
if ret != 0:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to create required log file! ({ret})")

#machine connection info (load dynamically)
ip = "172.23.4.53"
port = 8193


while True:
    #start connection to machine
    timeout = 10
    libh = ctypes.c_ushort(0)

    print(f"connecting to machine at {ip}:{port}")
    ret = focas.cnc_allclibhndl3(
        ip.encode(),
        port,
        timeout,
        ctypes.byref(libh),
    )
    if ret != 0:
        time.sleep(30.0)
        raise Exception(f"Failed to connect to cnc! ({ret})")
        
    sysinfoex = (ctypes.c_uint16 * 8)()
    sploadA = (ctypes.c_short * 3)()
    
    try:
        while True:
            
            print('--------------')
            print('CLASS - SYSINFO EX')
            print('--------------')
            #get sysinfo data from fanuc focus
            ret = focas.cnc_sysinfo_ex(libh, sysinfoex)

            if ret != 0:
                time.sleep(30.0)
                raise Exception(f"Failed to read sysinfo_ex! ({ret})")

            print('maximum controlled axes '+str(sysinfoex[0]))
            print('maximum spindle number '+str(sysinfoex[1]))
            print('maximum path number '+str(sysinfoex[2]))
            print('maximum machining group number '+str(sysinfoex[3]))
            print('controlled axes number '+str(sysinfoex[4]))
            print('servo axis number '+str(sysinfoex[5]))
            print('spindle number '+str(sysinfoex[6]))
            print('path number '+str(sysinfoex[7]))

            print('--------------')
            print('CLASS - SPINDLE LOAD 1')
            print('--------------')

            #get spinde 1 data from fanuc focus
            spindleNumber = ctypes.c_short(1)
            ret = focas.cnc_rdspload(libh, spindleNumber, sploadA)

            
            time.sleep(2)
    except:    
        print('failed to connect')
        time.sleep(5)
    
focas.cnc_exitprocess()
```

Comment: I don;t see any ***argtypes*** defined for functions. Could be a duplicate of [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: I've added the argtype near the top, I am still getting the same error

Comment: You added it for *cnc\_rdspload* only and that's wrong (both name and value).

Comment: Care to give a some constructive guidance other than "it's wrong"? I figured that out when it didn't work. All of the other functions work without issue. The cnc_rdspload is the only one not working, so it seemed logical to only add it for that one.

Comment: Guidance was in the *URL* from my previous comment (that for some reason was ignored), also the other mentioned question has a working example (and there are lots of other examples). As it should look like: `focas.cnc_rdspload.argtypes = (ctypes.c_ushort, ctypes.c_short, ctypes.POINTER(ODBSPN))`. Also you need that for all functions.

Comment: The URL was not ignored, I just don't know enough about ctypes to understand how the two tied together. I have tried `focas.cnc_rdspload.argtypes = (ctypes.c_ushort, ctypes.c_short, ctypes.POINTER(ODBSPN))`, `focas.cnc_rdspload.argtypes = (ctypes.c_ushort, ctypes.c_short, ctypes.POINTER(sploadA))`, and what is in the code above. All still result in a segmentation fault. If I need it for all functions, then why are all of the others already working without argtypes? (that is a serious question, not trying to be condescending).

Comment: Because you got lucky. For example the 8 uint16s passed to cnc_sysinfo_ex is too short and is probably overwriting the buffer. Declare the actual structure instead and an argtypes the defines the correct arguments including a pointer to that structure. Just because that function doesn’t fail doesn’t mean it is working correctly.  The overwriting might be why you can’t get the current failing function to work.

Comment: That makes sense. I will start there and rewrite the other functions and make sure they will work with the structures, and then try to work the sysinfo one back in and see if it makes any difference. If anything it'll make my code more readable. Thanks.

Comment: I am definitely going to tgo hrough and clean up the code, but I found out I was mis-informed by the client and the machine that I was connecting to did not have support for that specific function, which is why it didn't work. I connected to a different machine and it worked properly. That leads me back to my original question, is there a way to debug it / trace errors? In the past I have been able to view core dumps to see what error the library output, but this library does not seem to generate a core file anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does "*the machine that I was connecting to did not have support for that specific function*" mean? Was not exported by the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following resources (not sure which (if any) is official):

1. [[InventCom]: FWLIB32 | GENERAL](https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/general/fwlib32) (referenced in the question)
2. [[MultiDNC]: FOCAS2/Ethernet for Linux
   OPERATOR’S MANUAL](http://www.multi-dnc.com/software/FOCAS/Document/Linux/FOCAS2_Linux.pdf)
3. [[GitHub]: strangesast/fwlib - Fanuc FOCAS Library](https://github.com/strangesast/fwlib)

Also listing [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) (which this is a duplicate of), that also contains a brief *Undefined Behavior* explanation.

I created a small example of what (I thought) you're trying to do.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


DLL_NAME = "libfwlib32.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")

MAX_PATH = 0x100  # @TODO - cfati: Common value (Win specific). To be replaced with Fanuc constant value

MAX_SPINDLE = 8  # @TODO - cfati: Set it according to your model (https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/position/cnc_rdspload)
ALL_SPINDLES = -1

EW_OK = 0


# Formatting capabilities proxy class. For a more detailed representation, check: https://github.com/CristiFati/cfpyutils/blob/master/ctypes.py (WiP).
class Structure(cts.Structure):
    def __repr__(self):
        ret = [super().__repr__() + ":"]
        for name, _ in self._fields_:
            ret.append("  {:s}: {:}".format(name, getattr(self, name)))
        return "\n".join(ret) + "\n"


class PATH(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("system", cts.c_short),
        ("group", cts.c_short),
        ("attrib", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_axis", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_srvo", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_spdl", cts.c_short),
        ("reserved", cts.c_short),
    )

class ODBSYSEX(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("max_axis", cts.c_short),
        ("max_spdl", cts.c_short),
        ("max_path", cts.c_short),
        ("max_mchn", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_axis", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_srvo", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_spdl", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_path", cts.c_short),
        ("ctrl_mchn", cts.c_short),
        ("reserved", cts.c_short * 3),
        ("path", PATH * MAX_PATH),
    )

class ODBSPN(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("datano", cts.c_short),
        ("type", cts.c_short),
        ("data", cts.c_short * MAX_SPINDLE),
    )


def print_err(func, code=0):
    print("{:s} returned: {:d}".format(getattr(func, "__name__", "NO FUNC"), code))


def main(*argv):
    dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    cnc_startupprocess = dll.cnc_startupprocess
    cnc_startupprocess.argtypes = (cts.c_long, cts.c_char_p)
    cnc_startupprocess.restype = cts.c_short
    cnc_allclibhndl3 = dll.cnc_allclibhndl3
    cnc_allclibhndl3.argtypes = (cts.c_char_p, cts.c_ushort, cts.c_long, cts.POINTER(cts.c_ushort))
    cnc_allclibhndl3.restype = cts.c_short
    cnc_sysinfo_ex = dll.cnc_sysinfo_ex
    cnc_sysinfo_ex.argtypes = (cts.c_ushort, cts.POINTER(ODBSYSEX))
    cnc_sysinfo_ex.restype = cts.c_short
    cnc_rdspload = dll.cnc_rdspload
    cnc_rdspload.argtypes = (cts.c_ushort, cts.c_short, cts.POINTER(ODBSPN))
    cnc_rdspload.restype = cts.c_short
    cnc_freelibhndl = dll.cnc_freelibhndl
    cnc_freelibhndl.argtypes = (cts.c_ushort,)
    cnc_freelibhndl.restype = cts.c_short
    cnc_exitprocess = dll.cnc_exitprocess
    cnc_exitprocess.argtypes = ()
    cnc_exitprocess.restype = cts.c_short

    ret = cnc_startupprocess(0, b"focas.log")
    if ret != EW_OK:
        print_err(cnc_startupprocess, res)
        return -1
    ip = b"127.0.0.1"
    port = 22
    timeout = 2
    handle = cts.c_ushort(0)

    print(f"Creating handle for {ip}:{port}")
    res = cnc_allclibhndl3(ip, port, timeout, cts.byref(handle))
    if res != EW_OK:
        print_err(cnc_allclibhndl3, res)
        res = cnc_exitprocess()
        if res != EW_OK:
            print_err(cnc_exitprocess, res)
        return -2

    print(f"Lib handle: {handle.value:d}")

    odbsysex = ODBSYSEX()
    odbspn = ODBSPN()

    repeat = True
    while repeat:
        res = cnc_sysinfo_ex(handle, cts.byref(odbsysex))
        if res != EW_OK:
            print_err(cnc_sysinfo_ex, res)
            break
        print(f"ODBSYSEX data:\n{odbsysex:}")

        spindle = ALL_SPINDLES
        res = cnc_rdspload(handle, spindle, cts.byref(odbspn))
        if res != EW_OK:
            print_err(cnc_rdspload, res)
            break
        print(f"ODBSPN data:\n{odbspn:}")

        repeat = input("Repeat? ").lower() in ("y", "yes")

    res = cnc_freelibhndl()
    if res != EW_OK:
        print_err(cnc_freelibhndl, res)
        res = cnc_exitprocess()
        if res != EW_OK:
            print_err(cnc_exitprocess, res)
        return res

    res = cnc_exitprocess()
    if res != EW_OK:
        print_err(cnc_exitprocess, res)
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

There are some *@TODO*s there that I wasn't able to figure out.
Also (needless to say that) I don't have a *CNC* at my disposal, so I wasn't able to fully test the code.

**Output**:

> ```
> py_pc064_03.08_test0_lancer) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q077288502]> . ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls -lF
> total 1245
> -rw-r--r-- 1 cfati cfati    4497 oct 20 20:46 code00.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 cfati cfati 1264296 oct 20 20:36 libfwlib32-linux-x64.so.1.0.5
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 cfati cfati      29 oct 20 20:37 libfwlib32.so -> libfwlib32-linux-x64.so.1.0.5
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$(pwd) python ./code00.py
> Python 3.8.18 (default, Aug 25 2023, 13:20:30) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Creating handle for b'127.0.0.1':22
> cnc_allclibhndl3 returned: -17
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: This worked almost perfectly out of the box. I need to wait until Monday for them to run the machine again so I can see if I get the correct values but it is showing me data and not giving me errors so it seems to be working. Thank you